# How to create case-sensitive file in python on windows?

Tags: python, windows, filenames, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I want to create both A.txt and a.txt

```
f = codecs.open('A.txt', 'w', 'utf-8')
f = codecs.open('a.txt', 'w', 'utf-8')
```

But turned out it just created A.txt on windows.

Can it be forced to create case-sensitive file? If not on *nix.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100625

> As part of the requirements for POSIX compliance, the Windows NT File
>   System (NTFS) provides a case-sensitive file and directory naming
>   convention. Even though NTFS and the POSIX subsystem each handle
>   case-sensitivity well, 16-bit Windows-based, MS-DOS-based, OS/2-based,
>   and Win32-based applications do not.
>
> In NTFS, you can create unique file names, stored in the same
>   directory, that differ only in case. For example, the following
>   filenames can coexist in one directory on an NTFS volume: CASE.TXT
>   case.txt case.TXT However, if you attempt to open one of these files
>   in a Win32 application, such as Notepad, you would only have access to
>   one of the files, regardless of the case of the filename you type in
>   the Open File dialog box.

Even though it supports Case sensitive file names, if you use Win32 applications, you wont be able to enjoy that.

Answer (score 0):

Filenames on the NTFS file system (the default for Windows) are not case sensitive. From a quick search it seems that, if case sensitive filenames are important to you, you should just use a *nix OS. It's a significant effort to make Windows work with case sensitive filenames.

Comment: Filenames on NTFS are case sensitive. The Windows NT layer is also case sensitive. Windows usually enables the case insensitivity feature by default by setting ObCaseInSensitive=1 in the FS driver settings. But you can disable this feature and get case sensitivity back. As for *nix OSes, I'm not sure Mac OS X is case sensitive. Is it?

Answer (score -1):

NTFS is case-insensitive. `A.txt` and `a.txt` are the same filename.

Comment: -1 NTFS is not case insensitive, it is both case aware and case sensitive. Many userspace tools are case-insensitive, and for this reason Windows default setting is case-insensitivity but this can be changed in the registry and the underlying filing system is case sensitive.

Answer (score -1):

```
$ touch case.txt
$ touch CASE.txt
$ ls *.txt
case.txt  CASE.txt
```

you can make this work in *nix machine
but in windows I'm not sure that you can make this work